# Is it possible to run PyGears in VS Code?

Tags: pygears

I just started with PyGears, and there is no recommendation in the documentation or any tutorial about which IDE should be used for it.
I saw in tutorials that others are using Emacs(Spacemacs), but that text editor is too advanced for me.
I would like to use VS code. Is there any limitation with this IDE or everything should work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Spacemacs is a combination of Emacs & Vim thus it's quite advanced. But to run PyGears you can use any standard text editor, then compile it with a terminal command, something like:

```
python3 <python_file>
```

Also, it should run fine on most Python IDEs. I tested it on:

- VS Code
- Visual Studio
- PyCharm

and it worked fine.